# MongoDB: where to keep the accumulation data

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB to to keep some order info, which every document is like :

```
{
"order_id" : 1234567,
"order_time" : ISODate("2015-07-18T16:00:14Z")
"price" : 10,
"buyer_name" : "Jack" 
}
```

what I want to get is how much money every one spends every hour, what I now want to do is to keep an hour like 4:00 to 5:00 in a document and store them with time as key, and save a document like

```
{
accumulation_hour : ISODate("2015-07-18T16:00:00Z"),
    {"buyer_name" : "Jack", "accumulation" : 5000},
    {"buyer_name" : "Blabla", "accumulation" : 10000},
}
accumulation_hour : ISODate("2015-07-18T17:00:00Z"),
    {"buyer_name" : "Jack", "accumulation" : 5000},
    {"buyer_name" : "Blabla", "accumulation" : 10000},
}
```

Is this efficient? or what other choices do I have?
.

Comment: This is a very broad question even if you do not realize it. A general NoSQL principle and particularly with MongoDB and anything "document oriented" is to store the data according to how you most use it. That can mean either A. How you most read it, B. How you most write it (insert), C. How you most write "updates" for it, and D. { append other case array of possibilities to the list }. So "what is best" or "is it good" really depends on your usage patterns. Abundance of testing the different cases under expected loads usually yields the best results.

Comment: completely agree with @BlakesSeven, looking at what you have wrote its wage enough what i saw is that you currently store the document as per you 1st format and now as you have a need to get data in batch of hour you are thinking of new schema, instead go for a schema that will handle most of your application requirement and not single query requirement. If all the queries are time related queries think about timeseries data implementation.

Comment: @tintin  **what I want to get is how much money every one spends every hour** for this you can still get it done from your raw documents using Aggregation query with two group pipelines one on buyer_name and than order_date with sum on price

Comment: @Ninad, what kind of implementation is timeseries data implementation? I can get the result with aggregation now, just don't know if I should compute every time I used it or keep the data in a collection, If I keep it in a collection , how to design the table

Comment: @BlakesSeven, thx for ur comment, I'll try

Comment: Here is some help. [How to write the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)

Comment: @tintin theirs no better place than the official docs itself http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb